# Initializing with an expression of incompatible type even though it returns the right type

Tags: ios, objective-c

CGFloat color = [[myArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"redComponent"];
I know this array will return a float but xcode is saying: 
`Initializing 'CGFloat' (aka 'float') with an expression of incompatible type 'id _Nullable'`. I have NSLog'd the result even to check it. How do i get over this?

Comment: FYI - don't use `valueForKey:` to get a dictionary value. Use `objectForKey:`.

Comment: whats the difference?

Comment: Read the docs for the two and see.

Answer (score 2):

`objectAtIndex:` returns an *object*. `valueForKey:` returns an *object*. A CGFloat is not an object.

If you think this thing is an NSNumber object wrapping a number, then you can unwrap it, e.g. `floatValue`.